# What if the heat equation was of order n instead of order 2?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, laplacian

I am trying to understand the heat equation in one dimension, $$\partial_t u +\partial_x^2 u = 0$$
I've been introduce to the idea that as time goes to infinity that the function $u$ moves towards the average, and eventually flattens out to a horizontal line. I am wondering if $$\partial_t u +\partial_x^n u = 0$$

would have similar effects or descriptions. In the case $n=1$ it seems to me like, max's and min's which have 0 derivative with respect to $x$ would also have 0 derivative with respect to $t$, points at which the derivative is positive such as before a max,  would decrease to the previous min. Similarily points which are negative such as after a max, would increase to the previous max. So the end result would be like a Heaviside function, for initial conditions like $u(x,t)=sin(x)$.

What about $n=3,4$ for the initial condition case of $u(x,t)=sin(x)$ then things are similar but opposite, in the $n=4$ case the points which are not fixed with time, tend towards infinity as time increased. in the $n=3$ case the points which are moving towards the previous max, will move towards the next min, and similar for other cases.

My question is first, does this make sense, or where am I going wrong? Second is there anywhere I can go to find out more about the equation $\partial_t u +\partial_x^n u = 0$? Lastly, is there an analogue to "moving towards the average" for the $n$th order heat equation, like "moving towards the average of the average" for the 3rd order heat equation?

P.S. is the Laplacian of the Laplacian the $n=4$ scenario?

Comment: First, you have the sign wrong if you want to look at the heat equation, it should be $$\partial_{t}u\color{red}-\partial_{x}^{2}u=0$$ If you want to keep the $+$ sign, the $n = 3$ case is the [linearised KdV equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korteweg%E2%80%93de_Vries_equation) whilst the $n = 4$ case is the something like the [linearised Kuramoto-Sivashinsky equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuramoto%E2%80%93Sivashinsky_equation) without diffusion. Yes, the $n = 4$ case would be considered the (1-D) 'Laplacian of the Laplacian', sometimes called the biharmonic operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you say "would decrease to the previous min" it is important to remember that a derivative is a local rate of change, so that a decrease right now need not continue. For your $u_t+u_x = 0$ case with $u(x,0) = \sin(x)$, you don't get Heaviside, in fact a solution is $\sin(x-t)$.

A second point involves boundary conditions. PDE's usually have many solutions that have different behavior depending on the boundaries. For $u_t-u_{xx} = 0$ with $u(x,0) = \sin(x)$, one solution is $e^{-t}\sin(x)$, which satisfies the boundary conditions $u(0,t) = u(\pi,t) = 0$. But there are many other solutions that you can find in many books on differential equations, one solution for each case $u(0,t) = u(b,t) = 0$,
one for each choice of $b>0$ all having the same initial value $u(x,0) = \sin(x)$ for $0 <x < b$. Look in the section on Fourier series.